# Best practice with Notifications on iphone

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nsurlconnection

I'm implementing a system to view the progress of a download in Objective-C, using NSUrlConnetion.
Each time that I receive a part of a file I will send a notification by NSNotificationCenter, but with a file of 500-600 KB, how many message will I have? One for each byte or less? Is this a good way or is it too heavy?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us?

Answer (score 2):

The size of the packets that `NSURLConnection` receives in the `connection:didReceiveData` method vary based on the speed of your connection.  I've used `NSURLConnection` for downloading files up to 1.5GB and have always had good results updating a progress bar whenever `connection:didReceiveData:` is called.

The `NSData*` that you'll receive ranges from 2kb to 40kb.  For small files you're likely to only get one or two `connection:didReceiveData:` calls before `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called.

Answer (score -1):

You will definately have fewer. I'd say that it sounds like a solution that would work.